# SoftKeyboard Keywidth in keyboard xml file not displaying key background properly when shifted

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I m working on keyboard application. I am customizing SoftKeyboard code. My Keyboard view is like this.

[image]

But When is click shift button to capitalize all keys it changes the layout like this. 1st and 3rd row all keys background appear bigger.

[image]

Code when enter shift :

```
 private void handleShift() {
    if (mInputView == null) {
        return;
    }
    Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();

    if (currentKeyboard == mQwertyKeyboard) {    
        mQwertyKeyboard.setShifted(true);              
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyShiftedKeyboard);
        mQwertyShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(true);
    } else if (currentKeyboard == mQwertyShiftedKeyboard) {
        mQwertyShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(false);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
        mQwertyKeyboard.setShifted(false);
    }
}
```

I did't find any mistake yet. can anyone help me?

Comment: I think its the layout dynamic width problem, when you capitalise it, fonts become bit bigger than expected thats why its creating problem.

Comment: But see the 2nd row... haven't changed a bit..

Comment: ya its because the switch size in 3rd row is bit bigger then 1st row, i.e. backspace key, shift key. Check width of that images, you have to give fix size images or need to set dynamic layout @Vaishali

Comment: Okay thanks for ur help. But i don't think that is the problem..did u check the 1st row correctly? P key is out of screen so as backspace.

Comment: ya that is fine, but what I mean to say is, its the problem with design only and layout only, nothing else.

Comment: Okay. Is there other code related to shift thing i miss???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136949/discussion-between-pratik-dasa-and-vaishali-vaghasiya).